# Can't read integers value in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have a simple column family 'Users'

```
    System.out.println("  read User");
    long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    clientA.insert(ByteBuffer.wrap("mike".getBytes()), new ColumnParent("Users"), 
            new Column(ByteBuffer.wrap("email".getBytes())).setValue(ByteBuffer.wrap("mike@gmail.com".getBytes())).setTimestamp(timestamp)
            , ConsistencyLevel.ONE);

    clientA.insert(ByteBuffer.wrap("mike".getBytes()), new ColumnParent("Users"), 
            new Column(ByteBuffer.wrap("totalPosts".getBytes())).setValue(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(27).array()).setTimestamp(timestamp)
            , ConsistencyLevel.ONE);

    SlicePredicate predicate = new SlicePredicate();
    predicate.setSlice_range(new SliceRange(ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[0]), ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[0]), false, 10));

    ColumnParent parent = new ColumnParent("Users");

    List<ColumnOrSuperColumn> results = clientA.get_slice(ByteBuffer.wrap("mike".getBytes()), 
            parent, 
            predicate, 
            ConsistencyLevel.ONE);

    for (ColumnOrSuperColumn result : results) {
        Column column = result.column;
        System.out.println(new String(column.getName()) + " -> "+ new String(column.getValue())+", "+column.getValue().length);
    }
```

it returns

```
  read User
email -> mike@gmail.com, 14
totalPosts ->
```

So totalPosts can't be read with the thrift client

with cassandra-cli

[default@test] get Users['mike']['totalPosts'];
=> (column=totalPosts, value=0000001b, timestamp=1336493080621)
Elapsed time: 10 msec(s).

How can I retrieve this Integer value with Java thrift client?

using cassandra 1.1

edit:
it seems due to this part

```
for (ColumnOrSuperColumn result : results) {
        Column column = result.column;
        System.out.println(new String(column.getName()) + " -> "+Arrays.toString(column.getValue()));
    }
```

returns

```
email -> [109, 105, 107, 101, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109]
totalPosts -> [0, 0, 0, 27]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your column values are being returned as bytes, the same way you're inserting them. So the value for the 'email' column is `[109, 105, 107, 101, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109]`, which interpreted as ascii is `mike@gmail.com`. And the number 27 which you write into the ByteBuffer as `[0, 0, 0, 27]` (via the putint call) comes out the same way.

If you absolutely have to be using the raw thrift interface, you'll probably want to retrieve your totalPosts int using `ByteBuffer.getInt()`. But if at all possible, I recommend using a library to wrap around the ugliness of the thrift interface, which should take care of value serialization issues like this. Maybe look at [Hector](https://github.com/rantav/hector), or skip the old interface entirely and go straight to [CQL](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/references/cql/index) with [Cassandra-JDBC](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc/).